# Find an entry in a JSON list of objects based on object's key

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq

I've got JSON that, among other top-level content, includes the following:

```
{
  "organizationStructure": [
    {
      "id": 212119,
      "key": "level2"
    },
    {
      "id": 212112,
      "key": "level1"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I filter by the key to find only a given id (such as that for "level2")?

Comment: Please clarify whether the specified level can occur more than once in the input, and also what format the output should take, taking into account all the various possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or, to keep it simpler (or more complicated, depending on your point of view):

```
jq '.organizationalStructure[] |
    select(.key == "level1") | {id: .id}'
```

Often, it's nice to clean up the output:

```
jq -r '.organizationalStructure[] |
        select(.key == "level1") | {id: .id}.id'
```

As per PesaThe's suggestion in the comments, this can be simplified to:

```
jq -r '.organizationalStructure[] |
    select(.key == "level1").id'
```

and `{.id: id}` can be written simply `{id}`

Comment: Why not just `{id}` in the first example and `select(...).id` in the second? What am I missing?

Comment: You're probably not missing anything!  I post solutions to jq questions primarily to get feedback on my limited jq knowledge.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: My `jq` knowledge is also very limited, that's why I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [`select`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)). Note if there is more than one item with the key of `level2` this will only return the first:

```
.organizationalStructure | map(select(.key == "level2") | .id)[0]
```

Comment: Please correct the `organizationalStructure `. It should be `organizationStructure `